# Genesis Framework: Adding HTML code before </nav>

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

How can I add HTML code before the  when I use the Genesis Framework? 
I do not want to edit the menu.php inside the genesis/init/functions/ folder..

I hope there is a Genesis Framework expert out there!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Add this function into your child theme function.php

```
<?php add_filter('genesis_before_header','My_Html');
function My_Html(){ ?>
<!--Your HTML Code Here-->
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this filter **wp_nav_menu_items**

I suggest follow guided tutorials here: http://www.petersenmediagroup.com/genesis-framework/adding-simple-social-icons-search-form-genesis-menu/

Comment: Hi, I started to use the site today, sure I will keep this in mind. I am sure the filter, i gave above will be enough for the user to be on right path to solve the issue, but I wanted to make sure they have background info if they need so added the link.

Comment: Its ok. It is nice to use comments function :) Allowed to use comments just after your comment :)